# Hiding data in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our sql server userid and password is known to a third party who is using our data integrated with his application bypassing us. He also uses the windows authentication to login and gets all the data required from the client side. I need to hide a few columns from others in sql server. I am aware of the data encryption which is not feasible at this stage and there are too many reports to be modified.

1. Is there a way to open a database connection along with a symetric/asymetric key and then use the same regular sql statements to read the data?
2. How to block sql server from logging in using Windows authentication?

Comment: Belongs at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Instead of allowin access to a full table, create a view with only the "public" columns, and give thrid party only access to that view. That way they cannot see you sensitive data columns. Blocking SQL to access from windows autentication is easy, only remove the user from the database.

Comment: I don't understand. You need the views to be read only? If thats the case you only need to give permission for SELECT and not for update or insert...

Comment: So. what would be the problem? Just give thrid party on select permission on the view with the reduced columns

Comment: that doens't look like a good idea. You can achive the same with specific permissions

Comment: And that way you still can give update permission to thrid party people. You only need to take in account that if they insert record, the rest of the fields should be nulleable or have a default value.